# Объясните что такое обобщенный список в c#

Tags: c#, list, список

Объясните что такое обобщенный список в c#. Начал изучать C# имея некоторый бэкграунд на c++. Как я знаю списки существуют односвязные и двухсвязные. Используемая в C# конструкция `List<T> name = new List<T>` является чем то из вышеперечисленного, или это что то концептуально другое?

Comment: Нет, это другое. Это значит, что это может быть список любых (с некоторыми ограничениями) типов - строки, числа, классы... И это ключевое, что можно подставить вместо T любой (с ограничениями) тип, а метод обработки останется тот же. Внутри List - массив, при заполнении до определённого размера массив удваивается до ближайшего простого числа из специального справочника. Т.е. ведёт себя как динамический массив в терминах абстрактных типов данных. Есть и `LinkedList<T>` - вот это как раз под капотом двусвязный список. А односвязных списков в BCL нет.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php, https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes, https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level11/11_1.php